# Замена с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения в PHP преобразовать строку вида `hello @nickname (User)!` в `hello <a href="example.com/nickname">User</a>!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace(
    '/\s*\K@([^\s]+)[^\(]+\(([^)]+)\)/', 
    '<a href="example.com/$1">$2</a>', 
    'hello @nickname (User)!'
);
```

https://3v4l.org/SdfWd

Comment: `\s*\K` в `'/\s*\K@([^\s]+)[^\(]+\(([^)]+)\)/',` лишний

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, благодарю за правку.

Comment: Если вы хотели указать, что перед совпадением должен быть пробельный символ или начало строки, используйте `(?<!\S)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/^hello \@(\w+) \((\w+)\)\!$/', 'hello <a href="example.com/$1">$2</a>', $input_lines);
```